# Control or confounding? A case with two correlated categorical and continuous predictors

Tags: generalized-linear-model, multicollinearity, confounding, controlling-for-a-variable

Consider a case study which consists of two predictors (*Date* and *IndBin*) and one response variable (*Count*).
One predictor is ordinal (*Date*) and represents the day number within a season.
The other predictor is categorical (*IndBin*) with two levels and describes an individual's characteristic. One level of *IndBin* is very predominant in frequency (about 90% of records). For each individual I have just one value of *IndBin* but the observational study goes on for several years. *IndBi*n and *Date* are correlated because the rarer level of *IndBin* is more likely to occurr at the end of the season (in the last quartile of *Date*). In fact, the logistic regression of *Date* on *IndBin* results very significant.

Based on previous work I hypothesize that both *Date* and *IndBin* have a causal effect on *Count*. Thus, I want to investigate wether and how each one of these predictors affect a response variable (*Count*). I am using a negative binomial GLMM with zeroinflation but the question is not specific for this class of models. This is how the model loooks like:

Count ~ IndBin x Date + random = Year, zeroInflation = ~ IndBin x Date, family = "Negative Binomial"

Actually, I am somehow puzzled by the concept of confounding and control variables. I know that *Date* **causes** variation in *IndBin* (not vice versa) and an effect of *Date* on Count has largely been argued by observational studies. *Date* is therefore a confounding variable that I need to control in order to  investigate the effect of *IndBin* (adjusting for *Date*) on *Count*.
But on the other hand, *IndBin* and *Date* are very correlated and I have always been told that it is not good to keep correlated predictors in a model because it inflates their variance and therefore the type I error risk.

**Do you have any general suggestion on how may I try to test the effect of each predictor on *Count*?** I thought of building and comparing different models (e.g. by AIC) but I am not 100% sure on what are my a priori expectations. What would you do?

Comment: I have kept looking for answers and I have found a couple of useful links. I think that may help someone with a similar doubt.
The first is an answered question in Cross Validated:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81960/multicollinearity-when-adding-a-confounding-variable
The second is an article titled "Confounding: What it is and how to deal with it". 
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0085253815529748