# Solutions for multicolinearity

Tags: regression, multicollinearity

how do you linearly combine predictors, such as adding them together to avoid multicollinearity? I have multicolinearity in my regression. say the function is
`lm(y ~ x + z)` where x and z have collinearity. Is one solution to assess the individual regression `mod1 = y ~ x` and `mod2= y ~ z` then combine them. How would the combination work? how do you add these two together is it  y = the coef x from mod1 + coef of z from mod2?

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated! Can you tell us more about why you want to do this? I ask because there are many ways you could "solve" multicollinearity problems, and your choice of action might depend on the underlying reason you need to do it.

Comment: Sure, I would like to synthetically build y, and believe x and z represent y. However, when I combine the 2 predictors in an equation (x and Z) they do not behave well and have VIF of 9 for x and z has 3. Also, when I regress x and z against y by themselves they are significant and in the multivariable regression x is not.

Comment: Following up on the question from @LouisCialdella how do you intend to use (or interpret) your model of `y` once you have built the model? For example, if the model is for predicting values of `y` in new cases then there might be little or no problem arising from collinearity. Please add that information to the original question as comments can occasionally be lost.

Comment: it's for predicting values of y in new cases

Answer (score 1):

The usual goal in regression is to [include all relevant predictors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/204174/28500) in the model. Omitting important predictors correlated with included predictors can lead to reversed signs of regression coefficients in standard linear regression (see [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox)). In logistic or Cox survival regressions, omitting a predictor related to outcome will even [bias the coefficients of predictors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/204180/28500) with which it is not correlated. So starting with separate models for each of `x` and `z` is not a good way to proceed.

Multicollinearity (perhaps an over-statement in this case with only 2 predictors) gets a lot of attention but doesn't by itself necessarily lead to problems unless it's so [extreme](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/70899/28500) that you can't get reliable estimates of the coefficients. As [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/81965/28500) notes:

> ... the effects of collinearity are seen in the variances of the parameter estimates, not in the parameter estimates themselves.

The VIF, after all, is the Variance Inflation Factor for a coefficient.

What you are seeing is what you would expect if `x` and `z` are correlated with each other and if one or both are directly related to `y`. Then each of `x` and `z` could be significantly related to `y` individually (based on some *p*-value cutoff), but including both in a 2-predictor regression could lead to 1 of them appearing to be "not significant." It's quite possible in your 2-predictor model that `x` is still related to `y` in the same direction as it was individually, but that a high standard error for its regression coefficient (due to its correlation with `z`) made it fail to meet some *p*-value cutoff.

If your intent is prediction of `y` in new cases based on values of `x` and `z`, then there is no reason to omit either of `x` or `z`. In such a situation it's best to try to retain all variables related to outcome, even those that don't pass some particular test of statistical significance. Variable selection based on *p*-values or other relations to outcome "[only makes things worse](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18245/28500)." You do have to take precautions against overfitting or use other modeling approaches when the ratio of cases to predictors gets low, but with only 2 predictors that shouldn't be a problem provided you have more than a couple of dozen cases.